# Azure Mobile Services - Create new Account after Social Login

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-mobile-services

I try to combine 2 tutorials

1. Custom authentication providers http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/07/28/azure-mobile-services-net-updates/
2. Custom authentication http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-get-started-custom-authentication/

I want to create a new user Account with LinkedInLoginProvider (from 1 tutorial) like it was done with CustomLoginProvider (from 2 tutorial).

My question is - How to integrate with default owin login pipeline for external logins and where I must write my

```
    Account newAccount = new Account
                {
                   ...
                };
context.Accounts.Add(newAccount);
```

code.

Do I need to create new CustomRegistrationLinkedInController?

And how implement it?

Somebody can show me any example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matthew Henderson from Microsoft solved my question - "In that case, I would hook into the CreateCredentials() method of your LinkedInLoginProvider. This is a method that gets invoked after each login, between the point where the runtime has validated the identity, but before a token gets issued. Here you could check to see if the record already exists and if not create one. You actually get the UserID in this method as part of the tutorial."